# Tkinter Label y grid lento

Tags: python, tkinter

este pedazo de código muestra un [cuadro de punnett](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadro_de_Punnett), pero cuando se trata de 5 características o más se relentiza mucho, el problema creo que está en `Label` o en `grid` pues sin interfaz gráfica y únicamente con `print` va muy rápido, entonces quisiera que me ayudaran diciéndome una alternativa o solución a este problema por favor.

```
def tabla(todo):
    resultados = tk.Toplevel()
    frame = tk.Frame(resultados)
    ftabla, fbutton = font.Font(family="Open Sans", size=11), font.Font(family="Dubai Light", size=11)
    columna, contadorcomb = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(combf)):
        tk.Label(frame, text=combf[i], font=ftabla).grid(row=0, column=i+1)
    for i in range(len(todo)):
        if i == (len(combf)+1)*contadorcomb:
            tk.Label(frame, text=todo[i], font=ftabla).grid(row=contadorcomb+1, column=0)
            contadorcomb+=1
            columna = 0
        else:
            columna+=1
            tk.Label(frame, text=todo[i], font=ftabla, relief="groove").grid(row=contadorcomb, column=columna)
```

Para obtener `todo`:

```
todo, m= [], 0
    for i in range(len(punnett)):
        if i == len(combf)*m:
            todo.append(combm[m])
            m+=1
        todo.append(punnett[i])
```

Ejemplo de `punnett`, `combf`, `combm` y `todo (combinación de punnett y combm)`:

```
combf = ['ABCDE', 'ABCDe', 'ABCdE', 'ABCde', 'ABcDE', 'ABcDe', 'ABcdE', 'ABcde', 'AbCDE', 'AbCDe', 'AbCdE', 'AbCde', 'AbcDE', 'AbcDe', 'AbcdE', 'Abcde', 'aBCDE', 'aBCDe', 'aBCdE', 'aBCde', 'aBcDE', 'aBcDe', 'aBcdE', 'aBcde', 'abCDE', 'abCDe', 'abCdE', 'abCde', 'abcDE', 'abcDe', 'abcdE', 'abcde']
combm = combf
todo = ['ABCDE', 'AABBCCDDEE', 'AABBCCDDEe', 'AABBCCDdEE', 'AABBCCDdEe', 'AABBCcDDEE', 'AABBCcDDEe', 'AABBCcDdEE', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABbCCDDEE', 'AABbCCDDEe', 'AABbCCDdEE', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCcDDEE', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AaBBCCDDEE', 'AaBBCCDDEe', 'AaBBCCDdEE', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCcDDEE', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBbCCDDEE', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'ABCDe', 'AABBCCDDEe', 'AABBCCDDee', 'AABBCCDdEe', 'AABBCCDdee', 'AABBCcDDEe', 'AABBCcDDee', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcDdee', 'AABbCCDDEe', 'AABbCCDDee', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCDdee', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDDee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AaBBCCDDEe', 'AaBBCCDDee', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCDdee', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDDee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDDee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'ABCdE', 'AABBCCDdEE', 'AABBCCDdEe', 'AABBCCddEE', 'AABBCCddEe', 'AABBCcDdEE', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcddEE', 'AABBCcddEe', 'AABbCCDdEE', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCddEE', 'AABbCCddEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcddEE', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AaBBCCDdEE', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCddEE', 'AaBBCCddEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcddEE', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCddEE', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'ABCde', 'AABBCCDdEe', 'AABBCCDdee', 'AABBCCddEe', 'AABBCCddee', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcDdee', 'AABBCcddEe', 'AABBCcddee', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCDdee', 'AABbCCddEe', 'AABbCCddee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbCcddee', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCDdee', 'AaBBCCddEe', 'AaBBCCddee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBCcddee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCCddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'ABcDE', 'AABBCcDDEE', 'AABBCcDDEe', 'AABBCcDdEE', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBccDDEE', 'AABBccDDEe', 'AABBccDdEE', 'AABBccDdEe', 'AABbCcDDEE', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbccDDEE', 'AABbccDDEe', 'AABbccDdEE', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AaBBCcDDEE', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBccDDEE', 'AaBBccDDEe', 'AaBBccDdEE', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbccDDEE', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'ABcDe', 'AABBCcDDEe', 'AABBCcDDee', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcDdee', 'AABBccDDEe', 'AABBccDDee', 'AABBccDdEe', 'AABBccDdee', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDDee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbccDDEe', 'AABbccDDee', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccDdee', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDDee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBccDDEe', 'AaBBccDDee', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDDee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'ABcdE', 'AABBCcDdEE', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcddEE', 'AABBCcddEe', 'AABBccDdEE', 'AABBccDdEe', 'AABBccddEE', 'AABBccddEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcddEE', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbccDdEE', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccddEE', 'AABbccddEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcddEE', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBccDdEE', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccddEE', 'AaBBccddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccddEE', 'AaBbccddEe', 'ABcde', 'AABBCcDdEe', 'AABBCcDdee', 'AABBCcddEe', 'AABBCcddee', 'AABBccDdEe', 'AABBccDdee', 'AABBccddEe', 'AABBccddee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbCcddee', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccDdee', 'AABbccddEe', 'AABbccddee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBCcddee', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccDdee', 'AaBBccddEe', 'AaBBccddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AaBbccddee', 'AbCDE', 'AABbCCDDEE', 'AABbCCDDEe', 'AABbCCDdEE', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCcDDEE', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCCDDEE', 'AAbbCCDDEe', 'AAbbCCDdEE', 'AAbbCCDdEe', 'AAbbCcDDEE', 'AAbbCcDDEe', 'AAbbCcDdEE', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCCDDEE', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AabbCCDDEE', 'AabbCCDDEe', 'AabbCCDdEE', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCcDDEE', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AbCDe', 'AABbCCDDEe', 'AABbCCDDee', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCDdee', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDDee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AAbbCCDDEe', 'AAbbCCDDee', 'AAbbCCDdEe', 'AAbbCCDdee', 'AAbbCcDDEe', 'AAbbCcDDee', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcDdee', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDDee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AabbCCDDEe', 'AabbCCDDee', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCDdee', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDDee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AbCdE', 'AABbCCDdEE', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCddEE', 'AABbCCddEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcddEE', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AAbbCCDdEE', 'AAbbCCDdEe', 'AAbbCCddEE', 'AAbbCCddEe', 'AAbbCcDdEE', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcddEE', 'AAbbCcddEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCddEE', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AabbCCDdEE', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCddEE', 'AabbCCddEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcddEE', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AbCde', 'AABbCCDdEe', 'AABbCCDdee', 'AABbCCddEe', 'AABbCCddee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbCcddee', 'AAbbCCDdEe', 'AAbbCCDdee', 'AAbbCCddEe', 'AAbbCCddee', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcDdee', 'AAbbCcddEe', 'AAbbCcddee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCCddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCDdee', 'AabbCCddEe', 'AabbCCddee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbCcddee', 'AbcDE', 'AABbCcDDEE', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbccDDEE', 'AABbccDDEe', 'AABbccDdEE', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AAbbCcDDEE', 'AAbbCcDDEe', 'AAbbCcDdEE', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbccDDEE', 'AAbbccDDEe', 'AAbbccDdEE', 'AAbbccDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbccDDEE', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AabbCcDDEE', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbccDDEE', 'AabbccDDEe', 'AabbccDdEE', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AbcDe', 'AABbCcDDEe', 'AABbCcDDee', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbccDDEe', 'AABbccDDee', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccDdee', 'AAbbCcDDEe', 'AAbbCcDDee', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcDdee', 'AAbbccDDEe', 'AAbbccDDee', 'AAbbccDdEe', 'AAbbccDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDDee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDDee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbccDDEe', 'AabbccDDee', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccDdee', 'AbcdE', 'AABbCcDdEE', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcddEE', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbccDdEE', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccddEE', 'AABbccddEe', 'AAbbCcDdEE', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcddEE', 'AAbbCcddEe', 'AAbbccDdEE', 'AAbbccDdEe', 'AAbbccddEE', 'AAbbccddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccddEE', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcddEE', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbccDdEE', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccddEE', 'AabbccddEe', 'Abcde', 'AABbCcDdEe', 'AABbCcDdee', 'AABbCcddEe', 'AABbCcddee', 'AABbccDdEe', 'AABbccDdee', 'AABbccddEe', 'AABbccddee', 'AAbbCcDdEe', 'AAbbCcDdee', 'AAbbCcddEe', 'AAbbCcddee', 'AAbbccDdEe', 'AAbbccDdee', 'AAbbccddEe', 'AAbbccddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AaBbccddee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbCcddee', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccDdee', 'AabbccddEe', 'Aabbccddee', 'aBCDE', 'AaBBCCDDEE', 'AaBBCCDDEe', 'AaBBCCDdEE', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCcDDEE', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBbCCDDEE', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBBCCDDEE', 'aaBBCCDDEe', 'aaBBCCDdEE', 'aaBBCCDdEe', 'aaBBCcDDEE', 'aaBBCcDDEe', 'aaBBCcDdEE', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBbCCDDEE', 'aaBbCCDDEe', 'aaBbCCDdEE', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCcDDEE', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aBCDe', 'AaBBCCDDEe', 'AaBBCCDDee', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCDdee', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDDee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDDee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'aaBBCCDDEe', 'aaBBCCDDee', 'aaBBCCDdEe', 'aaBBCCDdee', 'aaBBCcDDEe', 'aaBBCcDDee', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcDdee', 'aaBbCCDDEe', 'aaBbCCDDee', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCDdee', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDDee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aBCdE', 'AaBBCCDdEE', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCddEE', 'AaBBCCddEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcddEE', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCddEE', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'aaBBCCDdEE', 'aaBBCCDdEe', 'aaBBCCddEE', 'aaBBCCddEe', 'aaBBCcDdEE', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcddEE', 'aaBBCcddEe', 'aaBbCCDdEE', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCddEE', 'aaBbCCddEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcddEE', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aBCde', 'AaBBCCDdEe', 'AaBBCCDdee', 'AaBBCCddEe', 'AaBBCCddee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBCcddee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCCddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'aaBBCCDdEe', 'aaBBCCDdee', 'aaBBCCddEe', 'aaBBCCddee', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcDdee', 'aaBBCcddEe', 'aaBBCcddee', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCDdee', 'aaBbCCddEe', 'aaBbCCddee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbCcddee', 'aBcDE', 'AaBBCcDDEE', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBccDDEE', 'AaBBccDDEe', 'AaBBccDdEE', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbccDDEE', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'aaBBCcDDEE', 'aaBBCcDDEe', 'aaBBCcDdEE', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBccDDEE', 'aaBBccDDEe', 'aaBBccDdEE', 'aaBBccDdEe', 'aaBbCcDDEE', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbccDDEE', 'aaBbccDDEe', 'aaBbccDdEE', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aBcDe', 'AaBBCcDDEe', 'AaBBCcDDee', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBccDDEe', 'AaBBccDDee', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDDee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'aaBBCcDDEe', 'aaBBCcDDee', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcDdee', 'aaBBccDDEe', 'aaBBccDDee', 'aaBBccDdEe', 'aaBBccDdee', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDDee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbccDDEe', 'aaBbccDDee', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccDdee', 'aBcdE', 'AaBBCcDdEE', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcddEE', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBccDdEE', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccddEE', 'AaBBccddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccddEE', 'AaBbccddEe', 'aaBBCcDdEE', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcddEE', 'aaBBCcddEe', 'aaBBccDdEE', 'aaBBccDdEe', 'aaBBccddEE', 'aaBBccddEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcddEE', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbccDdEE', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccddEE', 'aaBbccddEe', 'aBcde', 'AaBBCcDdEe', 'AaBBCcDdee', 'AaBBCcddEe', 'AaBBCcddee', 'AaBBccDdEe', 'AaBBccDdee', 'AaBBccddEe', 'AaBBccddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AaBbccddee', 'aaBBCcDdEe', 'aaBBCcDdee', 'aaBBCcddEe', 'aaBBCcddee', 'aaBBccDdEe', 'aaBBccDdee', 'aaBBccddEe', 'aaBBccddee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbCcddee', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccDdee', 'aaBbccddEe', 'aaBbccddee', 'abCDE', 'AaBbCCDDEE', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AabbCCDDEE', 'AabbCCDDEe', 'AabbCCDdEE', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCcDDEE', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCCDDEE', 'aaBbCCDDEe', 'aaBbCCDdEE', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCcDDEE', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aabbCCDDEE', 'aabbCCDDEe', 'aabbCCDdEE', 'aabbCCDdEe', 'aabbCcDDEE', 'aabbCcDDEe', 'aabbCcDdEE', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'abCDe', 'AaBbCCDDEe', 'AaBbCCDDee', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AabbCCDDEe', 'AabbCCDDee', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCDdee', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDDee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'aaBbCCDDEe', 'aaBbCCDDee', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCDdee', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDDee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aabbCCDDEe', 'aabbCCDDee', 'aabbCCDdEe', 'aabbCCDdee', 'aabbCcDDEe', 'aabbCcDDee', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcDdee', 'abCdE', 'AaBbCCDdEE', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCddEE', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AabbCCDdEE', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCddEE', 'AabbCCddEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcddEE', 'AabbCcddEe', 'aaBbCCDdEE', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCddEE', 'aaBbCCddEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcddEE', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aabbCCDdEE', 'aabbCCDdEe', 'aabbCCddEE', 'aabbCCddEe', 'aabbCcDdEE', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcddEE', 'aabbCcddEe', 'abCde', 'AaBbCCDdEe', 'AaBbCCDdee', 'AaBbCCddEe', 'AaBbCCddee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AabbCCDdEe', 'AabbCCDdee', 'AabbCCddEe', 'AabbCCddee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbCcddee', 'aaBbCCDdEe', 'aaBbCCDdee', 'aaBbCCddEe', 'aaBbCCddee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbCcddee', 'aabbCCDdEe', 'aabbCCDdee', 'aabbCCddEe', 'aabbCCddee', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcDdee', 'aabbCcddEe', 'aabbCcddee', 'abcDE', 'AaBbCcDDEE', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbccDDEE', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AabbCcDDEE', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbccDDEE', 'AabbccDDEe', 'AabbccDdEE', 'AabbccDdEe', 'aaBbCcDDEE', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbccDDEE', 'aaBbccDDEe', 'aaBbccDdEE', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aabbCcDDEE', 'aabbCcDDEe', 'aabbCcDdEE', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbccDDEE', 'aabbccDDEe', 'aabbccDdEE', 'aabbccDdEe', 'abcDe', 'AaBbCcDDEe', 'AaBbCcDDee', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbccDDEe', 'AaBbccDDee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AabbCcDDEe', 'AabbCcDDee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbccDDEe', 'AabbccDDee', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccDdee', 'aaBbCcDDEe', 'aaBbCcDDee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbccDDEe', 'aaBbccDDee', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccDdee', 'aabbCcDDEe', 'aabbCcDDee', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcDdee', 'aabbccDDEe', 'aabbccDDee', 'aabbccDdEe', 'aabbccDdee', 'abcdE', 'AaBbCcDdEE', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcddEE', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbccDdEE', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccddEE', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AabbCcDdEE', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcddEE', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbccDdEE', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccddEE', 'AabbccddEe', 'aaBbCcDdEE', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcddEE', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbccDdEE', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccddEE', 'aaBbccddEe', 'aabbCcDdEE', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcddEE', 'aabbCcddEe', 'aabbccDdEE', 'aabbccDdEe', 'aabbccddEE', 'aabbccddEe', 'abcde', 'AaBbCcDdEe', 'AaBbCcDdee', 'AaBbCcddEe', 'AaBbCcddee', 'AaBbccDdEe', 'AaBbccDdee', 'AaBbccddEe', 'AaBbccddee', 'AabbCcDdEe', 'AabbCcDdee', 'AabbCcddEe', 'AabbCcddee', 'AabbccDdEe', 'AabbccDdee', 'AabbccddEe', 'Aabbccddee', 'aaBbCcDdEe', 'aaBbCcDdee', 'aaBbCcddEe', 'aaBbCcddee', 'aaBbccDdEe', 'aaBbccDdee', 'aaBbccddEe', 'aaBbccddee', 'aabbCcDdEe', 'aabbCcDdee', 'aabbCcddEe', 'aabbCcddee', 'aabbccDdEe', 'aabbccDdee', 'aabbccddEe', 'aabbccddee']
```

Comment: ¿Has pensado en eliminar el `while`? Por lo que veo, tu primer `for` sirve para imprimir los datos de la fila que es la cabecera principal del cuadro;  el segundo `for` va recorriendo cada una de las filas restantes y, dependiendo si es la columna 0 o el resto, escribe un dato de cabecera o de contenido de la fila. Por lo tanto, no entiendo por qué añades un bucle `while`. Parece innecesario.

Comment: Benjamien estaria bien que pudieras poner un ejemplo real de los parámetros `punnett`, `combf` y `combm` para poder reproducirlo fácilmente. Posiblemente se pueda mejorar en algunos aspectos (el  `while ` es especialmente lento). No obstante, el cuello de botella no es ese, estas creando muchos widgets a al vez y eso implica mucho trabajo por detrás que no ves (instanciar un nuevo objeto, inicializarlo, agregar la referencia al padre, dibujarlo...). Si reutilizas la ventana se podria crear la tabla al inicio y posteriormente solo cambiar el texto de los labels y ocultar los que no se necesiten

Comment: Gracias a ambos por su respuesta, @FJSevilla no entiendo esa parte de reutilizar  la ventana y crear la tabla al inicio, ¿me lo podrías explicar un poco mejor por favor?

Comment: Me refiero a que si en tu programa, una vez abierto, creas varias tablas distintas a partir de distintos datos, introducidos por el usuario, por ejemplo. Es decir, el usuario introduce unos datos y a partir de ellos genera una tabla, posteriormente puede cambiar los datos y generar otra tabla. Si este es tu caso una opción es crear la tabla al arrancar el programa (esto seguirá siendo lento) y posteriormente reutilizas esa tabla las veces que auieras. En este caso solo modificas atributos pero no creas nuevas instancias cada vez que muestras una tabla nueva.

Comment: Otra opción que debería ser más eficiente (habría que probarlo) es usar `ListBox` o `TreeView` (ttk) para crear la tabla en vez de usar Labels. El problema es que Tkinter no tiene un widget para crear tablas, que es lo que necesitamos para esto.

Answer (score 2):

He optimizado un poco el código pero, como bien comenta @FJSevilla, el cuello de botella está en la creación de muchos objetos de `tkinter` dentro del bucle. Eso es lo que debes solucionar. Aquí te paso el código:

```
def tabla(punnett, combf, combm):
  resultados = tk.Toplevel()
  frame = tk.Frame(resultados)
  ftabla, fbutton = font.Font(family="Open Sans", size=11), font.Font(family="Dubai Light", size=11)
  filas, columnas, contadorpunnett = 0, 0, 0
  for filas in range(33):
    if filas == 0:
      for columnas in range(1, 33):
        tk.Label(frame, font=ftabla, text=combf[columnas-1]).grid(row=0, column=columnas)
      continue
    for columnas in range(33):
      if columnas==0:
        tk.Label(frame, font=ftabla, text=combm[filas-1]).grid(row=filas, column=0)
        continue
      tk.Label(frame, font=ftabla, text=punnett[contadorpunnett], relief="groove").grid(row=filas, column=columnas)
      contadorpunnett+=1
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Aquí he mejorado el código un poquito más, localizando la llamada a la creación del objeto de tkinter dentro del bucle en un solo lugar, para que te sea más fácil de optimizar ese cuello de botella:

```
def tabla(punnett, combf, combm):
  resultados = tk.Toplevel()
  frame = tk.Frame(resultados)
  ftabla, fbutton = font.Font(family="Open Sans", size=11), font.Font(family="Dubai Light", size=11)
  fila, columna, contadorpunnett = 0, 0, 0
  for fila in range(33):
    for columna in range(33):
      if fila == 0 and columna == 0:
        continue
      if fila == 0:
        texto = combf[columna-1]
      elif columna == 0:
        texto = combm[fila-1]
      else:
        texto = punnett[contadorpunnett]
        contadorpunnett += 1
      tk.Label(frame, font=ftabla, text=texto).grid(row=fila, column=columna)
```

Comment: Sí, gracias va un poco más rápido

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán En el último código, si en lugar de pasar por parámetros a la función de manera separada el contenido del cuadro, la cabecera principal de la fila superior y la cabecera correspondiente a los primeros valores (primera columna) de cada fila, se pasase todo junto en una matriz no haría falta el segundo `if` (con sus correspondientes `elif` y `else`) dentro del bucle. Ni tampoco haría falta un `contadorpunnett`. Directamente se asociaría a `text` algo así => `cuadro[fila][columna]`.

Comment: Exacto, Genial, me diste una idea muy buena voy a guardar en un vector al principio combf luego la primer fila de punnett seguida de combm[0] y luego la segunda fila de punnett, seguida de combm[1] y así sucesivamente con un ciclo for. Así podré imprimir todo de corrido y no habrá if. El único problema serían los bordes de la tabla punnett

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán justo iba a comentar eso. Si creas una matriz (listas anidadas) con la tabla completa solo necesitarás usar dos for anidados, eliminando los condicionales. Si haces esto no veo ya más margen de mejora posible, usando labels al menos.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con el nuevo código con la matriz, pero aún así sigue lento, supongo que el problema es el método Label en sí.

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán Me refería a si en el momento que guardas los valores por primera vez en `combf`, `combm` y `punnett`, no lo puedes guardar todo junto en una sola matriz de filas y columnas (arrays dentro de un array) en lugar de guardarlo en las tres variables. De la manera que lo haces incluso te va más lento, porque recorres todos los datos dos veces: una para acomodar las tres variables en una variable `todo` y otra para resolver el problema.

Comment: @CarlosUrda Aaa ya, no no se puede es que junto con la tabla vienen unos botones con funciones que trabajan con los tres datos. Lo que podría hacer es en una sola matriz  hacer lo que me dices y luego, cuando se haga click en algún botón, ya sea extraer los datos de la primer matriz, o hacerlo otra vez, es decir, crear la matriz, lo cual no creo conveniente.

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán De todas formas, aunque partieses de una matriz con los datos, sigues teniendo el problema del cuello de botella de `Label` dentro del bucle. Tienes que buscar una forma de no crear un `Label` por cada celda. De Tkinter no sé nada, ahí no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Sí es lo que pienso, talvez Tkinter o Label no sea para estas cosas, voy a probar con PyQt para hacer una tabla realmente. Gracias